# Sonido en un Alert de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Espero me puedan apoyar con la siguiente duda.

Al momento de enviar un `alert` en una validación quisiera que también saliera un sonido junto con el `alert` como puedo hacer eso.

He probado varias cosas pero no me funcionan espero me puedan orientar.

Gracias.

```
<audio src="Imagenes/alarma_fuerte.mp3" id="sonido"></audio>
<input type="button" id="alarma" value="sonaaaar !!!">

<script type="text/javascript">


    document.getElementById('#sonido').play();
    alert("elertaa !! ");

</script>
```

Comment: Coloca lo que has intentado para que así todos podamos entender lo que propones.

Comment: listo lo que quiero hacer es que al momento que me salga una alerta de java script tambien se reprodusca un sonido eso es todo @LeviArista

Comment: posiblemente esté mal tu ruta, sin ingresas `[tu_ruta]/Imagenes/alarma_fuerte.mp3` en tu navegador, que sale?

Comment: la ruta esta correcta ya que el archivo html donde lo quiero reproducir esta en raiz

Comment: ¿Con que navegador estas probando ?

Comment: sin ingresas `[tu_ruta]/Imagenes/alarma_fuerte.mp3` en tu navegador, que sucede?

Comment: con navegador chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `play` para reproducir tu `audio`:

HTML:

```
<audio id="xyz" src="tuAudio.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('xyz').play();
alert("Alerta");
```

Comment: solo me sale la alerta no me reproduce ningun sonido

Comment: te aseguraste de hacer bien la referencia a tu audio?

Comment: sii claro y solo me sale el alert

Comment: el audio se encuentra en la misma carpeta?... procura llamar bien el js

Comment: si me funciona el unico detalle que lo puebo en una archivo en limpio y cuando lo cargo primero sale la alerta y luego el sonido muy bien hasta ahi... pero cuando lo paso a mi proyecto al momento de cargarlo suena y no es lo que quiero... quiero que se dispare el sonido cada vez que salga alguna alrta.... como puedo hacer eso.

Comment: Te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta, añade el código de como estás mandando a llamar la función y así te podremos ayudar.

Comment: ya lo solucione muchas gracias solo tenia que poner el .play dentro del condicional junto con la alert para que se dispararan los dos al mismo tiempo gracias :)

Comment: Genial (Y), espero haberte ayudado con la publicación. Saludos.

Comment: si gracias ya te la marque como positiva muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Sin jugar con HTML :

Te recomiendo crear otra función

```
 var myAudio= document.createElement('audio');
 var myMessageAlert = "";
 myAudio.src = 'audio.mp3';
 myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    alert(myMessageAlert);
 });
function Myalert(message) { 
    myAudio.play();
    myMessageAlert = message;
} 
Myalert("Mensaje");
```

Pero en caso de querer sobrescribir `alert()`, es lo mismo que lo anterior pero cambias el nombre de la función.

```
function alert(message) { 
  myAudio.play();
  myMessageAlert = message;
} 
alert("Mensaje");
```

Actualizado; Se agrega evento ended al elemento dinamico audio.

> El evento ended ocurre cuando el audio / video ha llegado al final.

Comment: no funciona solo sale el alert

Comment: Tienes que poner el archivo .mp3 en la misma carpeta que tienes el .js

Comment: bien bien ya quedo muchas gracias

Comment: el unico destalle es que la alarma suena despues de dar aceptar al boton de la alerta me gustaria que sonara antes y apareciera la alerta como lo puedo hacer ??

Comment: si me funciona el unico detalle que lo puebo en una archivo en limpio y cuando lo cargo primero sale la alerta y luego el sonido muy bien hasta ahi... pero cuando lo paso a mi proyecto al momento de cargarlo suena y no es lo que quiero... quiero que se dispare el sonido cada vez que salga alguna alrta.... como puedo hacer eso.

Comment: listo muchas gracias solo hay que poner el .play con el alert dentro del condicional donde va aparecer el alert gracias :)